# Read 0.9.0 messages with KafkaConsumer 0.10.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to read messages from a 0.9.0 broker with a `KafkaConsumer` of version 0.10.0?

Reading the documentation I see a description of how to upgrade brokers from 0.9 to 0.10 in a way that they keep working with existing logs. The broker can even be instructed then to send 0.9 messages still to old consumers.

But I am looking for the other way round: new consumer, old broker.

Naivly trying, I get an exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 1142898, only 2701 bytes available
```

Is there a way to tell the 0.10.0 consumer to expect old style messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've opened a similar issue in Kafka Jira and got a quite unambiguous answer - upgrade brokers first, then clients, not vice versa. This ensures all the functionality needed to handle your request is implemented and the broker can handle it gracefully.

Here's the link for the issue I opened if you are interested in details - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2496.

Comment: Read it. I like the rationale that this way only the broker needs to talk different versions.